# Calculating LookAt position from rotation and translation matrix

Tags: camera, matrix, view, frustum-culling

I was wondering if it was possible to calculate a lookat position from the translation and rotation matrices (aka the building blocks of my view matrix). I need the lookAt position to implement a special type of frustum culling, but my program does not use the lookat position, so I was looking for a simple solution to calculate it.

Comment: Any point along the camera's forward axis can be used as a look-at position. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Okay, thanks so much for the tip

Comment: Actually, how would I go about calculating the forward vector of the camera?

Comment: Depends on your framework/tech stack. Sometimes it's the camera's local +z, sometimes -z, though more exotic choices are conceivable. What can you tell us about how you've coded this camera?

Comment: I made my own framework using metal (Apple Graphics API) I have access to the camera position, worldup, view matrix, rotation (in both degrees and radians) and the translation data

Comment: Sounds like those would be good details to add to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view matrix is the inverse of the object's camera transformation, and the inverse of a rotation matrix is just its transpose, so the 3rd row is your camera's local forward vector.

Add some multiple `d` of the third row of your view matrix to your camera position to get a point `d` units in front of your camera along its forward axis.

(This is equivalent to multiplying the vector `(0, 0, d, 1)` by the camera's transformation matrix, or the inverse of the view matrix, just skipping redundant ops for the zero terms)

Using that as a look-at point will give the same result as your current camera orientation, since your camera is already looking at it.

Some APIs treat negative `d` values as "in front" of the camera, while others say that's behind and positive is in front, so flip the sign on `d` if you initially get the wrong answer.